# Typescript third party definition file - class missing method definition - how do I expand the definition?

Tags: typescript

The following class definition file:
https://github.com/Bitcoin-com/bitbox-javascript-sdk/blob/master/lib/HDNode.d.ts

is missing the `createAccount()` method here:
https://github.com/Bitcoin-com/bitbox-javascript-sdk/blob/master/lib/HDNode.js#L144

I am attempting to use the `createAccount()` method and the typescript compiler is giving me an error. I'd like to be able to move past this error while keeping the rest of the class definition. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea would be to use a [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), which would look something like this:

```
declare module "bitbox-javascript-sdk/lib/HDNode" { 
  interface HDNode { 
    createAccount(hdNodes: any): any;
  }
}
```

(To make this a module augmentation rather than a module declaration, it needs to be inside another module, i.e., either put it in a file that has top-level imports or exports or wrap it in `declare module "dummy" { }`.)

I'm unsure of the correct parameter and return types, but if you know the correct code pattern to use `createAccount`, declaring the parameter and return types as `any` will at least get you unblocked.  (I think the existing method declarations are wrong.  Many of them come in pairs with and without an argument of type `HDNode`, but looking at the source, it appears that that argument is always required and its actual type is not the `HDNode` class of `bitbox-javascript-sdk` but what is referred to as `_bitcoincashjsLib2.default.HDNode` in the [JavaScript code](https://github.com/Bitcoin-com/bitbox-javascript-sdk/blob/5dec4828b01a14014527f03bcb0388463702dd7a/lib/HDNode.js).)

Comment: Can you expand on how to go from declaration -> augmentation. I actually tried to "patch" the class by doing similar things as the code you have there but ran into issues where it overrode the module entirely.

Comment: I don't have anything more to say about module augmentations.  If your code isn't working, please add it to the question so I can see exactly what you tried.